# Decoupling Input from Update/Physics Movement in a Game Engine

Tags: architecture

I have some troubles figuring out how to decouple the input handling from the physics part (includes movement).

My Game loop looks like this

```
while GAMEISRUNNING
    HandleInput()
    Update()
    Render()
```

From what I have found on the internet I can do something like this in the `HandleInput` method

```
HandleInput()
{
    if A key is pressed
        MOVEFORWARD = true
    ...
}
```

and then in the `Update` I can just check the boolean flags and update properly. The problem is that my `Update` method uses the `Physics Engine` to iterate over the entities and call their `Integrate` method. This means that I cannot just adjust the position because the integrate method is the same for all the entities.

```
Integrate(float deltaTime)
{
    #position and velocity are vectors
    position += velocity * deltaTime
}
```

Where can i actually perform the update to movement in this scenario? I was thinking that in the global `Update` method I can iterate over all the entities before the physics engine and adjust their velocities. That means that every GameObject will have `GameObjectUpdate` method and there I can  adjust the velocities accordingly. This means that the global `Update` method will iterate over all the entities twice. Generally O(n) is pretty good, but I am not sure if this is the optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all unusual to have a separate "game logic update" step and "physics integration" step in a game engine.

The physics is generally integrated by a specialized library with just that one responsibility, so logic specific to each game entity needs to be processed elsewhere.

As some examples, [in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) a `FixedUpdate` method can be called on every object, before each iteration of the physics engine's integration, followed by collision messages and post-physics coroutines:

[image]

[Unreal Engine uses the concept of "Ticking Groups"](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Actors/Ticking) controlling when certain game logic should be stepped - PrePhysics, DuringPhysics, or PostPhysics, among others.

Iterating over the objects twice or more might seem wasteful, but it can actually be more efficient in some scenarios. A tight loop that does just one consistent thing to all objects, accessing similar data structures (eg. collision broadphase data) will tend to make good use of the processor's cache and branch prediction features.

If you had a mixed group of objects needing different types of game logic updates, or none at all, and some needing physics updates, or none at all, and tried to update them all in one loop, the processor would have to spend more of its time figuring out which kinds of updates to run, and looking up the instructions/data for update type C (since the cache is full of update type A & B). So the single loop might not be much faster or could even be slower than doing the steps in their own tight loops on just the objects that need them.